# Allow any AWS resource from an account to publish to an SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

[According to the AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_Sns.html#AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCase4_Sns), this policy allows any S3 bucket to send a notification to an SNS topic:

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Id":"MyAWSPolicy",
    "Statement" :[
        {
            "Sid":"My-statement-id",
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Principal" :"*",
            "Action":"sns:Publish",
            "Resource":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111122223333:My-Topic",
            "Condition":{
               "StringEquals":{
                  "AWS:SourceAccount":"444455556666"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to do the same for an SQS queue instead of an SNS topic. This Policy doesn't work:

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Id":"MyAWSPolicy",
    "Statement" :[
        {
            "Sid":"My-statement-id",
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Principal" :"*",
            "Action":"sqs:SendMessage",
            "Resource":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111122223333:My-Queue",
            "Condition":{
               "ArnLike":{
                  "aws:SourceArn":"arn:aws:s3:*:111122223333:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This (allowing every AWS account in the world) works:

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Id":"MyAWSPolicy",
    "Statement" :[
        {
            "Sid":"My-statement-id",
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Principal" :"*",
            "Action":"sqs:SendMessage",
            "Resource":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111122223333:My-Queue",
            "Condition":{
               "ArnLike":{
                  "aws:SourceArn":"arn:aws:s3:*:*:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I try to restrict it with the Principal, it doesn't work again:

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Id":"MyAWSPolicy",
    "Statement" :[
        {
            "Sid":"My-statement-id",
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Principal" :"111122223333",
            "Action":"sqs:SendMessage",
            "Resource":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111122223333:My-Queue",
            "Condition":{
               "ArnLike":{
                  "aws:SourceArn":"arn:aws:s3:*:*:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

By "doesn't work" I mean that the Policy is accepted as valid, but when I try to configure an S3 bucket to send a notification (NotificationConfiguration) I get the error:

```
Unable to validate the following destination configurations : Permissions on the destination queue do not allow S3 to publish notifications from this bucket
```

Comment: Is the principal the user that is uploading files to S3? I don't think that's going to be the principal AWS uses to send S3 notifications to SNS. What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Are you trying to limit one bucket to send notifications to an SNS topic? Or are you trying to limit one user of one bucket to trigger notifications to an SNS topic?

Comment: I am trying to make the SQS writable from anything uploaded in S3, given that only AWS IAM users created for this AWS account can upload files. I am not interested in limiting access outside of avoiding notifications from buckets of other accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restricts access to specific AWS account, you need to add nested block `AWS` under `Principal`:

```
"Principal": {
  "AWS": "111122223333"
},
```

or with multiple accounts:

```
"Principal" : { 
  "AWS": [ 
    "123456789012",
    "555555555555" 
  ]
}
```

See [AWS JSON policy elements: Principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html) for details.